# Understanding a bash script

Tags: python, linux, bash

I am new to bash and wanted to learn what this code is trying to do, if it is done poorly or with errors and how it can be improved.

```sh
COMMAND=$1

case $COMMAND in
    "upgrade")
        UPSCRIPT=`ls -t ./assets/upgrade | head -n1`
        python ./assets/upgrade/$UPSCRIPT | tee >> biglog.txt
        VERSION=$(echo $UPSCRIPT | awk -F. '{print $1}')
        echo `date` $VERSION > ./version.txt
        test -e ./artifcts && rm -rf ./artifacts      
     ;;

    "downgrade")
        DOWNSCRIPT=`ls -t ./assets/downgrade | head -n1`
        python ./assets/downgrade/$DOWNSCRIPT | tee >> biglog.txt 
        VERSION=$(echo $UPSCRIPT | awk -F. '{print $1}')
        echo `date` $VERSION > ./version.txt
        test -e ./artifcts && rm -rf ./artifacts      
    ;;
    *)
        while read -r UPSCRIPT; do
            python $UPSCRIPT | tee >> biglog.txt
            VERSION=$(echo $UPSCRIPT | awk -F. '{print $1}')
            echo `date` $VERSION > ./version.txt
            test -e ./artifcts && rm -rf ./artifacts      
        done <<< $(find "./assets/update" -type f -name "*.py")
esac
```

Comment: Check it with https://shellcheck.net and then come back.  `<<< $(` prefer `< <(` over `<<<$(` but anyway, just do `find ... | while read` - no reason to use redirection here. `| tee >> biglog.txt` - remove `| tee`, it's useless. Use `find` instead of `ls`, but it willl require some scripting.

Answer (score 1):

- Use lower case variable names. Upper case is recommended for environment and shell internal variables.
- Use `$()` instead of `` `...` ``. It nests better.
- use parameter expansion instead of running a command in a subshell, if possible. It's much faster.
- Where the logic of the script was unclear, I left a comment in the code.

```sh
#! /bin/bash
command=$1
artifacts=./artifacts

case "$command" in
    upgrade)
        upscript=$(ls -t ./assets/upgrade | head -n1)
        python ./assets/upgrade/"$upscript" | tee >> biglog.txt
        version=${upscript%.*}
        echo $(date) "$version" > ./version.txt
        test -e "$artifacts" && rm -rf "$artifacts"  # artifacts or artifcts?
     ;;

    downgrade)
        downscript=$(ls -t ./assets/downgrade | head -n1)
        python ./assets/downgrade/"$downscript" | tee >> biglog.txt
        version=${downscript%.*}  # upscript or downscript?
        echo $(date) "$version" > ./version.txt
        test -e "$artifacts" && rm -rf "$artifacts"
    ;;
    *)
        while read -r upscript; do
            python "$upscript" | tee >> biglog.txt
            version=${upscript%.*}
            echo $(date) "$version" > ./version.txt
            test -e "$artifacts" && rm -rf "$artifacts"
        done <<< $(find "./assets/update" -type f -name '*.py')
esac
```

- I would probably also extract the common logic from *upgrade* and *downgrade* to a function to avoid repetition.
- Parsing the output of `ls` or `find` is suspicious, as file names can contain weird characters. I'd need to understand more what you're trying to do to fix that.